# Get records with max value on grouped SQL results (mysql)

Tags: mysql

How do you get the rows that contain the max value on created_dt for each by conversation_id grouped set?

I've seen some complicated variations on similiar questions, and none with a good answer. 
I've put together a simple example:

```
id | member_a_id | member_b_id | conversation_id | created_dt          | content
1  | 100         | 110         | 1               | 2018-04-01 12:00:00 | aaa
2  | 100         | 110         | 1               | 2018-04-01 13:00:00 | bbb
3  | 105         | 100         | 2               | 2018-04-01 14:00:00 | ccc
4  | 110         | 100         | 1               | 2018-04-01 15:00:00 | ddd
5  | 100         | 110         | 1               | 2018-04-01 16:00:00 | eee
```

Desired result set:

```
member_a_id | member_b_id | conversation_id | created_dt          | content
100         | 110         | 1               | 2018-04-01 16:00:00 | eee
105         | 100         | 2               | 2018-04-01 14:00:00 | ccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get max(created_dt) of each conversation and then join it with main table in this way:

> ```
> select   tbl.*
> from     tbl
> join     (select   conversation_id, max(created_dt) created_dt
>           from     tbl
>           group by conversation_id) t1
> on       tbl.conversation_id = t1.conversation_id
> and      tbl.created_dt = t1.created_dt;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | member_a_id | member_b_id | conversation_id | created_dt          | content
> -: | ----------: | ----------: | --------------: | :------------------ | :------
>  3 |         105 |         100 |               2 | 2018-04-01 14:00:00 | ccc    
>  5 |         100 |         110 |               1 | 2018-04-01 16:00:00 | eee
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5ca9d41c50d4bb793388b22ee00f63f)*</kbd>

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.